# how do I add multiple filtering to product in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
how do I add filtering to product in mongoose and the filtering will have some foreign reference such 
as category, brand ,color?

after receiving the category and brand as slug , i query them on their model to find the _id 

my code:


    let category = req.query.category || ''
    let brand = req.query.brand || '' 
    if(!category && !brand){
            allProduct = await Product.find({admin_id:admin_id , is_active:true})
                                            .sort({ _id: -1 })
                                            .select(select)
                                            .skip((page-1) *limit)
                                            .limit(limit)  
        }
        else if(category&& !brand && !...){
            allProduct = await Product.find({admin_id:admin_id , is_active:true , 
                                      category_ids:category._id})
                                            .sort({ _id: -1 })
                                            .select(select)
                                            .skip((page-1) *limit)
                                            .limit(limit) 
        }
```

> Here the query parameter has the slug as value not _id, I have to find the product that matches 
>       foreign _id. I did query to find the _id of brand category by using slug value.
>       This query parameter can sometimes be null and sometimes has both value exits.
>       I am  using mongoose. How to complete this query because now it looks not ok. cause i may have to 
>       filter 
>       **CATEGORY BRAND COLOR AND SO ON**
>         So how to complete this query .
>         similarly it looks rough and for many query option i have to go and check lots of condition.
>         And i am very limited with my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution i came up with is to create an object with all the query fields. 
initially i will have an empty object. then if the **Query Params** is active i search for it's it, and push the _id to my object.The **Query Params** will have slug as input. 
such as:

```
const query ={}
let category = req.query.category
const cat_id = await Categoryl.find({slug:category }).select('_id')
cat_id? query.category_id  = cat_id._id ? null

cont product = await Product.find(query)
```

make sure all the instance or key's of query object must be same as the Product Schema
   such that :

```
if Product model has category_id then put same key in query
query.category_id =n....
```

Below i have attached my solved code.

```
exports.getProduct = async (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
        const admin_id  = req.params.admin_id
        const limit = +req.query.limit || 10
        const page = +req.query .page || 1
        const search = req.query.search || ''
        let category = req.query.category 
        let brand = req.query.brand 
        const query ={}
        query.admin_id =admin_id,
        query.is_active = true
        if(category){
            category = await Category.findOne({admin_id:admin_id , is_active:true, slug:category}).select('_id')
            category ?query.category_ids = category._id :null
        }
        if(brand){
            brand = await Brand.findOne({admin_id:admin_id , is_active:true,slug:brand}).select('_id')
            brand ? query.brand_id = brand._id.toString() : null

        }


        let allProduct = []
        const count = await Product.find({admin_id:admin_id , 
         is_active:true}).countDocuments()
        const select = 'name slug photo price special_price new_to special_price_end 
           newProduct -_id'


            allProduct = await Product.find({...query})
                                            .sort({ _id: -1 })
                                            .select(select)
                                            .skip((page-1) *limit)
                                            .limit(limit)                                           



    return res.status(200).json({
        count:count,
        body:allProduct,
        error:false
    })
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        error:true
    })
}
}
```